# Palindrome question use of lambda and key

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

Hey guys so I was working on this problem on the algoExpert platform, but I am struggling to understand what **longest and currentLongest** are really doing.

```
def longestPalindromicSubstring(string):
  currentLongest = [0, 1]
  for i in range(1, len(string)):
    odd = getLongestPalindromeFrom(string, i - 1, i + 1)
    even = getLongestPalidromeFrom(string, i - 1, i)
    longest = max(odd, even, key=lambda x: x[1] - x[0])
    currentLongest = max(longest, currentLongest, key=lambda x: x[1] - x[0])
  return string[currentLongest[0] : currentLongest[1]]

def getLongestPalindromeFrom(string, leftIdx, rightIdx):
  while leftIdx >= 0 and rightIdx < len(string):
    if string[leftIdx] != string[rightIdx]:
      break
    leftIdx -= 1
    rightIdx += 1
  return [leftIdx + 1, rightIdx]
```

Just from the beginning, I am not entirely sure what the `currentLongest = [0, 1]` is doing, is it just saying that it will have 2 values?
Are odd and even returning an array of indices?
`longest` I know it is taking the max between odd and even, key seems to be taking an **anonymous function lambda ** but I'm not too sure what **key** does and what **x: x[1] - x[0]** does. I also don't understand what `currentLongest` is doing with the max. Like what is the purpose of passing `longest` and `currentLongest`? They are both lists so I am not fully sure what is even going on there. And in the return, if we get something like `[3:9]` on `longest`, I think all we are doing is slice the string as `string(3:9)` but the use of lists is confusing me and the `max` and `key:lambda` are confusing me more. Any help is appreciated!

*Description:
Write a function that, given a string, returns its longest palindromic substring.
A palindrome is defined as a string that's written the same forward and backward. Note that single-character strings are palindromes.
You can assume that there will only be one longest palindromic substring.*

Sample Input:

```
string = "abaxyzzyxf"
```

Sample Output:

```
"xyzzyx"
```

Thanks to Daniel Hao for asking for more clarifications and thanks to Prasad Darshana for the suggestions on how to better format my code lines. I am new to Stack Overflow so that's very helpful so I can know how to format and ask better questions next time!

Comment: Can you elaborate the problem `description` more?  Even though I can guess, but would rather not.  And can you provide sample input/outputs to make it clear? Eg. what if the string is `afternoon`  or `abc123defabc321`?

Comment: @DanielHao sure let me quickly add them!

Comment: if you feel some of the Posts helpful, please accept and upvote them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Difference between `currentLongest` and `longest`

`currentLongest` keeps track of the start and end indices of the longest Palindrome it has found so far through iterations. `currentLongest` is initialized as `currentLongest = [0,1]`, so even if the string is 1 character long, the for loop will not execute and return the single character (via `return string[currentLongest[0]:currentLongest[1]]`).

`longest` keeps the start and end indices of the longest palindrome found in a single iteration. This is retrieved by performing a lambda operation on 2 arrays: odd and even.

- what x: x[1] - x[0] does?

The lambda operation compares two arrays, odd and even in this way (x denotes each array): It takes each array and subtracts the start index (0) from the end index(1), and outputs the array which has the maximum difference/ distance between start and end indices. (Which indicates the longest substring palindrome)

Comment: Ohhh so in longest, you will run the lambda function for the even array of idx, and then again for the odd array of idx, so pretty much the key:lambda is doing that for even and odd array of idx, and then returns the max of them? And then currentLongest does the same exact thing for the longest array(current) and the old one currentLongest?

Comment: @AdilsonJurado Yes exactly! You've got the point.

Comment: Wow, so when we use a key in max(), are the other 2(odd and even) jut like parameters to pass to the key, and then key is the one returning the actual max???

Comment: Yes. If 2 arguments are passed, they are like parameters to the function specified in the key. So when each array gets passed as arguments, the key will receive the index differences of each array. Then it will perform max operation on returned index differences.
This article might help to get more information on this: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-use-key-function-in-max-and-min-in-python-1fdbd661c59c

Comment: Thanks so much! It is more clear now! Thanks so much to you and everyone else who contributed!

Answer (score 2):

After some guessing, I think I figure this out, and would suggest that you try the following code to see if that can help you understand the `posted` code better:
**[Notes]** this is not direct answer, rather try to demystify the complex code and propose alternative to solve this problem, or as a reference.

```
def longestPalindromeSub(string):
    N = len(string)
    for i in range(N)[::-1]:
        for idx in range(N-i):
            word = string[idx: idx+i+1]
            if word == word[::-1]:     # palindrome is symmetric 
               return word
    return ''  # not found
```

Running with word = 'racecar'

```
>>> print(longestPalindromeSub(word))
    `racecar`

>>> print(longestPalindromeSub('mississippi'))
    'ississi'
```

Answer (score 1):

`currentLongest = [0, 1]`, this is the initial assumption. in this code assume that the longest palindromic substring is a string which start from 0 and end from 1.

for example:

if given string is `abcdc` it assume `currentLongest` as `a` (from index 0 to 1).

Then in the for loop in `longestPalindromicSubstring` function, it checks and increases the index by one. in `even`, and `odd` cases. it gets even length and odd length substrings to check. You can check the length by the values that pass into `getLongestPalidromeFrom` function. ( `(i-1),(i),(i+1) length= 3` `odd` ).

in `getLongestPalidromeFrom` function it increases length by two and checks is it palindromic or not. then return the longest palindromic sub string that can generate **by starting given points** .

in `longest` it checks what is the longest substring from `odd` and `even` length strings. and then in `currentLongest` it compares the new longest value with the previous longest (cuurentLongest) value.

Remember indexes in `currentLongest, longest` are the indexes of starting and endpoints of the sub-string. So length equal to `x[1]-x[0]`. the lambda function.

there can be some mistakes in indexing in my explanation. but totally idea is this.